# Connecting BUTT to a second shoutcast stream

Tags: streaming, shoutcast, internet-radio

I am trying to connect BUTT to a second stream source on my shoutcast server. The first stream works fine as Shoutcast Administration shows it as stream #1. It is connected through a seperate machine running MIXXX and is working fine. It also shows the stream #2 information so I've confirmed it's active. (see screenshot)

This is my sc_serv.conf file:

```
   password=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
   requirestreamconfigs=1
   streamadminpassword_1=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
   streamid_1=1
   streampassword_1=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
   streampath_1=stream
   streamid_2=2
   streampassword_2=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
   streampath_2=radio
   logfile=logs/sc_serv_2.log
   w3clog=logs/sc_w3c.log
   banfile=control/sc_serv.ban
   ripfile=control/sc_serv.rip
   streamauthhash_1=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I want to connect BUTT to the streamid_2 stream. How does one configure BUTT to do this for shoutcast? It has no ability to indicate the stream ID in the software. I appreciate the help to get this second stream connection.

[Butt Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztHQH.png)

[Shoutcast Server Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj2AC.png)

[Butt Config for connecting to stream 2 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50D3n.png)

Just need help configuring BUTT to connect to the 2nd stream.

Comment: Changing the password in BUTT to indicate the SID worked.  example`mypassword:#2` where #2 is the stream_id and I had to include the hash sign. However, I am unable to set that value in my darkice.cfg file.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this was to place the stream ID at the end of the password for the streampassword_2:

```
 streamid_2=2
 streampassword_2=mypassword:#2
 streampath_2=radio
```

Subsequently, if you have a #3, 4,5.. you add that number after the password accordingly.

Comment: Worked for me, there's also a button "Source connection details" on the admin left menu that shows those passwords, didn't think they were important. Thanks.